# How to receive base64 data from Nodejs and display using jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am using images or other times of files in my database as a blob. Once I retrieve that blob I put that in a buffer and convert to base64 like this:

```
file = Buffer.from(blob,'binary').toString('base64');
res.send(file)
```

Now, in my jquery :

On success after the post route is fired I want to receive the file:

```
 success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        console.log('image uploaded and form submitted');     
      }
```

But the `console.log` shows that the entire file is just this:
`W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd`

From my understanding of buffer it is just a small memory allocation used to transfer large sets of data one at a time. So I think I am only getting the first buffer? How do I get the entire buffer?

Comment: Did you try decoding this string? You'll see that `atob("W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd") === "[object Object]"`... So obviously you are passing an object where a string was expected. I'd bet that your `blob` is not a string, yet you pass `'binary'` as encoding, instructing node to transform your _string_ (which isn't a string) to a buffer. Try removing the encoding argument.

Comment: Also, why do you even send base64 at all? It would make sense if you'd embed it in other data, but it seems this is the only data you send, so why not just send the file directly? (or even better, stream it.)

Comment: I do not know how to do that so I will do some research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd is the base64 for [object Object]

You must check what the `blob` is actually, its not a string of data, its a javascript object, contains the whole row of the database, or something else.

The objects.toString() is called when passed into buffer.from

I would suggest using `console.log(blob)` and you will be happy.